# Поиск динамически созданного элемента jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, search

Есть функция в которой при загрузке скрипта перебираюся все

```
$("#groups input[type=button]") // где input созданны динамически
```

Как мне найти динамически созданный элемент посредствами jQuery?!
Делал это и раньше, только тогда были события *click* или *change*.
А мне нужен перебор без никаких действий от пользователя, сразу при загрузке.

Дело в том, что у меня функция должна срабатывать при загрузке страницы и ресайзе:

```js
$(function () {
    //...
    AdaptiveFilter();     // здесь НЕ работает поиск динамических элементов
    $(window).resize(function() {
        AdaptiveFilter(); // здесь работает поиск д.э
    });
    //...
});
```

И Код функции:

```js
function AdaptiveFilter() {
        if ($(window).width() > 750) {
            var rowWidth = $("#groups").width();
            var countItems = Math.floor(rowWidth / (200 + 5));
            var inputOrder = -1;
            var detailsOrder = 0;
            
            $("#groups input[type='button']").each(function() {
                if (($(this).index()/2) % countItems == 0) {
                    inputOrder += 2;
                }
                else {
                    inputOrder++;
                }
                $(this).css("order", inputOrder);
                });
            $(".details").each(function() {
                if((($(this).index()-1)/2) % countItems == 0) {
                    detailsOrder += countItems + 1;
                }
                $(this).css("order", detailsOrder);
            });
            $(".details").width(countItems * 200);
        }
        else {
            $(".filterCategory").children().each(function() {
                $(this).css("order", 0);
            });
            $(".details").width("100%");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "динамически созданный элемент посредствами jQuery" - созданный **до** перебора? Тогда никаких дополнительных действий не нужно.

Comment: @Igor спасибо за подсказку, однако похоже у меня дело не в том. Добавил код вверху

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы, которые не находит первый вызов `AdaptiveFilter();`, создаются позднее. Было бы странно, если бы нашлись элементы, которых еще нет.

В коде вопроса не хватает стрелочки со словами "Динамические элементы создаются здесь!"

```
function AdaptiveFilter() {
  console.log('$("#groups input[type=button]").length = ', $("#groups input[type='button']").length); 
  // что выводится в консоль браузера?
  ...
```

Comment: В DOM они уже есть, а стили не добавляет. Даже после полной прогрузки страницы. А при ресайзе, все отлично.

Comment: При первой загрузке выводит = 0, при ресайзе = 13

Comment: @KobetsMatviy Вы, как, будете говорить, где они "динамически создаются", или это секрет?

Comment: Вы правы, нужно на свежую голову поискать. Где-то напартачил! Спасибо от души, за помощь!!

Comment: @KobetsMatviy Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Comment: Динамически создаются в другом файле, вытаскиваю AJAX с API

Comment: @KobetsMatviy О-о-о, ну все ясно. В слове AJAX - одна из "А" значит "асинхронно".

Comment: тогда как решить эту задачу?!))

Comment: Собственно, вызывать `AdaptiveFilter()` *после* создания DOM-элементов.

Comment: Имеется ввиду в том самом файле где они и создаются, верно?!

Comment: Да. Или передавать туда обработчик, внутри которого вызывать `AdaptiveFilter()`.